# shortcode to insert text depending on day of week

Tags: wordpress, datetime, shortcode

I would like to create a shortcode of [time] that would display 6:00-7:00AM everyday except for Saturday or Sunday, as those two days would display the time 8:00-9:00AM.  How would I do this?

This is what I have come up with...

```html
// [time]  
function displaytime(){  
if (date('l') == 'Saturday' || date('l') == 'Sunday')){
   echo '8:00-9:00AM';
}else{ //it's a weekday
echo '6:00-7:00AM';
   }
}  
add_shortcode('time', 'displaytime'); 
// end display time
```

What it currently looks like... (next to Sat and Sun it should display 8:00-9;00AM)
[image]
I have 7 shortcodes to display the next 7 days of the week. So perhaps this is what is causing it to not work correctly?

```html
// [tomorrow]  
function displaydate_tomorrow(){  
    return date('D, M j.', strtotime('+1 day')); 
}  
add_shortcode('tomorrow', 'displaydate_tomorrow'); 
// end tomorrows date
// [tomorrow2]  
function displaydate_tomorrow2(){  
    return date('D, M j.', strtotime('+2 day')); 
}  
add_shortcode('tomorrow2', 'displaydate_tomorrow2'); 
// end tomorrows date2
// [tomorrow3]  
function displaydate_tomorrow3(){  
    return date('D, M j.', strtotime('+3 day')); 
}  
add_shortcode('tomorrow3', 'displaydate_tomorrow3'); 
// end tomorrows date3
// [tomorrow4]  
function displaydate_tomorrow4(){  
    return date('D, M j.', strtotime('+4 day')); 
}  
add_shortcode('tomorrow4', 'displaydate_tomorrow4'); 
// end tomorrows date4
// [tomorrow5]  
function displaydate_tomorrow5(){  
    return date('D, M j.', strtotime('+5 day')); 
}  
add_shortcode('tomorrow5', 'displaydate_tomorrow5'); 
// end tomorrows date5
// [tomorrow6]  
function displaydate_tomorrow6(){  
    return date('D, M j.', strtotime('+6 day')); 
}  
add_shortcode('tomorrow6', 'displaydate_tomorrow6'); 
// end tomorrows date6
// [tomorrow7]  
function displaydate_tomorrow7(){  
    return date('D, M j.', strtotime('+7 day')); 
}  
add_shortcode('tomorrow7', 'displaydate_tomorrow7'); 
// end tomorrows date7
// [time]  
function displaytime(){  
    if (date('D') == 'Saturday' || date('D') == 'Sunday'){
        return '8:00-9:00AM';
    }else{ //it's a weekday
        return '6:00-7:00AM';
    }
}  
add_shortcode('time', 'displaytime'); 
// end display time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stated in [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/add_shortcode):

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode.

try with this, and don't hesitate to comment if there is any issue:

```
// [time]  
function displaytime(){  
    if (date('l') == 'Saturday' || date('l') == 'Sunday'){
        return '8:00-9:00AM';
    }else{ //it's a weekday
        return '6:00-7:00AM';
    }
}  
add_shortcode('time', 'displaytime'); 
// end display time
```

**EDIT after question update:** The reason it displays the same time for all 7 places is because your initial code tests `date('l')` which only consider current day, so it will display '6:00-7:00AM' everywhere if current day is not Saturday or Sunday, or else '8:00-9:00AM' everywhere. In addition to this, you are creating 8 different shortcodes when only 1 should be enough for the 7 days, and the last for the time should be merged too, or else it has no way of knowing which day we consider.

**EDIT 2**: added code to set the wordpress timezone setting for the function, then restore to its original setting that was before the function.

updated code with a single shortcode for all (now you learn to add attributes to a shortcode!):

```
// use examples: [nextdaytime day="+1 day"]  [nextdaytime day="+2 day"]
function displaynextdaytime($atts){
    $originalZone = date_default_timezone_get(); //save timezone
    date_default_timezone_set(get_option('timezone_string')); //set it to your admin value
    $time = strtotime($atts['day']); //time for the date() function based on our 'day' attribute
    if (date('l', $time) == 'Saturday' || date('l', $time) == 'Sunday'){
        $timeStr = '8:00-9:00AM';
    }else{ //it's a weekday
        $timeStr = '6:00-7:00AM';
    }
    $returnVal = date('D, M j.', $time) . ' ' . $timeStr;
    date_default_timezone_set($originalZone) //restore original zone
    return $returnVal;
}
add_shortcode('nextdaytime', 'displaynextdaytime'); 
// end display next day and time
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  However, the time 6:00-7:00AM is displaying next to every date. I have updated my initial question with more details.

Comment: @user6738171 updated my answer, now you should be able to use this single shortcode for your 7 days, you just have to update the attribute with any relative date format for the day you want, in your case: "+1 day", "+2 day", "+3 day", "+4 day", "+5 day", "+6 day", "+7 day"

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I really appreciate it.  One last concern.  If I use [nextdaytime day="+1 day"] it is showing the next day as Saturday June 30, even though it is currently Thursday, June 29 7:45PM.  Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: @user6738171 something weird in your last comment, the June 29 is a Friday (today actually), Thursday was the 28. Is your date_default_timezone set to the good value? You can verify by displaying `date_default_timezone_get()`. Also fixed an extra round bracket syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  Yes, yesterdays date (Thursday) was actually the 28.  In wordpress my default time is Chicago time.  However for this function, I think Wordpress is using the Universal time by default for this, which is quite a few hours ahead.  As it says, Universal time (UTC) is 2018-06-29 11:19:34. Local time is 2018-06-29 06:19:34

Comment: That's most probably the cause. The way i would do it without interfering other functions/plugins is first: get original timezone in a variable, second: set the timezone to your admin setting, then last: restore the original setting you saved in your variable. Edited the code to reflect that (you'll have to wait for tonight to properly test it), tell me if this works ;)